# How to combine two selects or two querys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two querys. First:

```
SELECT TOP 10   NewsItemTitle
            ,   COUNT(1) AS CounterNews
FROM [ACTIVITY]
WHERE [UserLocation] = 'United States'
GROUP BY NewsItemTitle
ORDER BY CounterNews DESC
```

returns me this:

```
NewsItemTitle                                                        CounterNews
Afinan plan para casas con cuota de $180.000 por mes                      5
The Exploratoreum's STEM seller                                           4
Witnesses at Hasan trial describe carnage of Ft. Hood shootings.          2
U.S. returns to FIFA top 20 after two-year absence                        2
Sunnyvale: Police shoot and kill man; body of woman found inside house    1
...
```

and, in addition, I want to add on that query the fields `[NewsItemUrl]` and `[NewsItemPublisher]`:

```
SELECT  [NewsItemUrl]
    ,   [NewsItemPublisher]
FROM [ACTIVITY]
```

So, how can I combine those 2 querys into 1?

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: Are there multiple URLs for one NewsItemTitle? If so, how should the result look like?

Comment: thanks @TToni,  each news has a publisher and url, if grouped by title, I have to show also the corresponding url and a publisher for the title clustered.

I mean, if I group by title, a title also corresponds to a single url and a single publisher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT TOP 10
      NewsItemTitle 
    , [NewsItemUrl] = MAX([NewsItemUrl])
    , [NewsItemPublisher] = MAX([NewsItemPublisher])
    , COUNT(1) AS CounterNews
FROM dbo.[ACTIVITY]
WHERE [UserLocation] = 'United States'
GROUP BY NewsItemTitle
ORDER BY CounterNews DESC
```

Or this -

```
SELECT TOP 10
      NewsItemTitle 
    , [NewsItemUrl]
    , [NewsItemPublisher]
    , COUNT(1) AS CounterNews
FROM dbo.[ACTIVITY]
WHERE [UserLocation] = 'United States'
GROUP BY 
       NewsItemTitle 
    , [NewsItemUrl]
    , [NewsItemPublisher]
ORDER BY CounterNews DESC
```

Comment: Might be a bit premature depending on what the OP wants. Maybe including Url and Publisher in the group would be the better option.

Comment: @TToni possible you are right. Waiting for a user reply... :)

Comment: these scripts worked properly agree to expectations.
I mean, I'm grouping by title, but each news with a title for it also has a url and associate publisher. great response!, thnks for all of you! @TToni Additionally I must say that the first script works properly. the second script works and brings me good, but not exactly the same data returns. but, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you want to include two columns which are not part of the `GROUP BY`. That is not allowed normally, you either have to include them in the group by or aggregate them in another way(f.e. `MIN/MAX/COUNT`).

But you could use a [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like `ROW_NUMBER` in a common-table-expression:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT NewsItemTitle, 
           NewsItemUrl, NewsItemPublisher,
           CounterNews = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NewsItemTitle),
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NewsItemTitle ORDER BY CounterNews DESC)
    FROM [ACTIVITY] 
    WHERE [UserLocation] = 'United States' 
)
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

As you can see the [`OVER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause works also on aggregate functions like `COUNT` which allows to count each group without using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ummm, I generates an error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @Makito: Missing comma perhaps, what version of sql-server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Devart's answer, but if you don't want to group by NewsItemUrl and NewsItemPublisher, here is another way you can achieve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [NewsItemUrl]
     ,  [NewsItemPublisher]
    , TMP.NewsItemTitle
    , CounterNews
FROM [ACTIVITY] ACT
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT TOP 10   NewsItemTitle
            ,   COUNT(1) AS CounterNews
FROM [ACTIVITY]
WHERE [UserLocation] = 'United States'
GROUP BY NewsItemTitle
ORDER BY CounterNews DESC
) TMP ON ACT.NewsItemTitle = TMP.NewsItemTitle
```